# Cannot access mongodb through browser - It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I open terminal and enter the following commands

```
sudo mongod
```

which then outputs

```
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I open another terminal and enter

```
sudo mongo
```

which open the mongo shell and prompts for mongo commands, but when I go to localhost/27017 I receive the following message:

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

I created a simple nodejs application using express and when I `POST` data it seems the mongodb gets hung up. This is the message which I receive in the terminal in which I start my express application and the page never posts the data. So I believe the problem lies within mongo but I cannot figure it out.

```
POST /info 200 120002ms
```

Here is my express code

```
var Info = require('../models/info');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var join = path.join;

exports.form = function(req,res){

    res.render('info', {
        myName: 'Michael'
    });
};

exports.submit = function(){
console.log('Within exports.submit 1');
    return function(req,res,next){
        console.log('Within exports.submit 2 ');
        var firstName = req.name.first;
        var lastName = req.name.last;
        Info.create({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName
        },function(err){
            if(err) return next(err);

            res.redirect('/')
        });
    }
};
```

Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/info');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('info',schema);
```

app.js

```
...
app.get('/info',info.form);
app.post('/info',info.submit);
...
```

Comment: Are you getting the message when testing access with a web browser, or where are you seeing this message?

Comment: yes, I am getting the message in a web browser

Comment: @WiredPrairie there is app.post() in express not mongodb, when I go to localhost/28017 I receive a page not found error.

Answer (score 70):

**Before Mongo 3.6**:

You may start mongodb with

```
mongod --httpinterface
```

And access it on

```
http://localhost:28017
```

Since version 2.6: MongoDB disables the HTTP interface by default.

**Update**

> HTTP Interface and REST API
>
> MongoDB 3.6 removes the deprecated HTTP interface and REST API to
>   MongoDB.

See [Mongo http interface and rest api](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/index.html#http-interface-and-rest-api)

Answer (score 16):

MongoDB has a simple web based administrative port at 28017 by default.

There is no HTTP access at the default port of 27017 (which is what the error message is trying to suggest). The default port is used for native driver access, not HTTP traffic.

To access MongoDB, you'll need to use a driver like the [MongoDB native driver for NodeJS](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). You won't "POST" to MongoDB directly (but you might create a RESTful API using express which uses the native drivers). Instead, you'll use a wrapper library that makes accessing MongoDB convenient. You might also consider using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) (which uses the native driver) which adds an ORM-like model for MongoDB in NodeJS.

If you can't get to the [web interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#http-status-interface), it may be disabled. Normally, I wouldn't expect that you'd need it for doing development unless you're checking logs and such.

Comment: Do I also have to establish a connection using 'mongodb' or can I simply use 'mongoose' to connect to the database. I posted my express code above. thanks

Comment: You can just use Mongoose to connect to the database (assuming you've started it, as shown early in your question).

Answer (score 8):

Like the previous comment mention, the message "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." its a warning because you are missunderstanding this line:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/info');
and browsing this url:
http://localhost:28017/

However, if you want to see the mongo's admin web page, you could do it, with this command:

mongod --rest --httpinterface

browsing this url:
http://localhost:28017/

the parameter httpinterface activate the admin web page, and the parameter rest its needed for activate the rest services the page require

Answer (score 4):

HTTP interface for MongoDB Deprecated since version 3.2 :)

Check Mongo Docs: [HTTP Status Interface](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface)

Comment: Can you please add a reference to the deprecation?

Answer (score 2):

I am in ubuntu 14.04 and mongod is registered as an upstart service. The answers in this post sent me in the right direction. The only adaptation I had to do to make things work with the upstart service was to edit `/etc/mongod.conf`. Look for the lines that read:

```
# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
# httpinterface = true
```

Just remove the `#` in front of httpinterface and restart the mongod service:

```
sudo restart mongod
```

> Note: You can also enable the rest interface by adding a line that reads `rest=true` right below the httpinterface line mentioned above.