# Can we Connect to mongodb on Azure windows VM from another Azure windows VM

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm working on a NodeJS project that using Azure VM to deploy.
want to connect and communicate between 2 virtual machines which are in a group. so i can use the one vm for data and 2nd for web I've created a config file .yaml for mongo with all the parameters like

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "logs path"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "datapath"
security:
   authorization: "enabled"
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Does anybody have experience in configuring mongodb on Azure VM which has windows?

Comment: You should probably be binding to 0.0.0.0, and then if the two VMs are in the same virtual network, there is absolutely no issue, as long as the firewall allows the outside connection.

Comment: i tried it but no luck @juunas

Comment: in the mongo vm when i try to access the localhost:27017 i was getting this message **It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.** but in the web vm i am not getting anything when i tried to access status 200

Answer (score 0):

According to some research online - windows firewall is your problem, disable the firewall or allow port 27017 and you are good to go.

Also, it appears you are configuring MongoDB wrong. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446876/cannot-access-mongodb-through-browser-it-looks-like-you-are-trying-to-access-m). And [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/).

Comment: i added port for Mongo in mongo db server and in web server too I've disabled the firewall in web server  too but no luck :-( i'v been trying since a week but no use and i am able to get elastic search access on both machines i sincerely don't under stand why mongo is not accessible @4c74356b41

Comment: try changing bindIp to the actual internal IP of your Azure VM @MysticForce

Comment: i tried even doing it but no use. i am really sorry for annoying you guys i don't really get the reason why it isn't working i tried almost all scenarios i was able to get elastic search working i don't know why. this crazy mongo doesn't work

Comment: thank you very much for the help it was **@** in my password which i passed in mongo URL i changed the password it worked fine thank you once again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help it was just a **@** in my password which i gave it on my url Mongo doesn't like it like %40 instead of @. 
issue solved.