# VPS not respond to request MongoDB-NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request, vps

I bought a VPS server and installed Nodejs and Mongodb in it. Then I transferred my existing database file to mongodb, which I set up on VPS. I made the connection via NodeJS. The database seems to be working, but when I make a request, for example http://serverip:port/fetchData, I get the following error

'It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.'
could you please help me to solve this problem?

Here is NodeJs connection code

```
const URL = "mongodb://serverIp:port/dbname";


const connection = mongoose
  .connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
    family:4
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Successfully Connected DB"))
  .catch((e) => console.log("DB CONNECTION ERROR: "+e));

module.export = connection;
```

Note --> I added my desktop ip to access mongodb database and I can easily manage with my own desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot access mongodb through browser - It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446876/cannot-access-mongodb-through-browser-it-looks-like-you-are-trying-to-access-m)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP interface for MongoDB Deprecated since version 3.2 :)

Check Mongo Docs: HTTP Status Interface

Comment: const URL="mongodb+srv://APPNAME:PASSWORD@CLUSTER_CONNECTION/MYDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";  When I change the URL part in NodeJS with the database I opened on mongodb.com, I can send a request and easily fetch data. Frankly, I'm a little confused. Do I need to use a different method to request a VPS server? @Angels

Comment: Did you try this command: `mongod --rest --httpinterface`

browsing this url: `http://localhost:28017/`

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it states that there is no such command. @Angels 
I just started learn these things (Ubuntu,VPS..) Thougth that I may have messed up some settings so  I decided to  reset the server, I will try from the beginning with ubuntu 20 operating system. Although I still do not understand the problem, if I solved I will share the results here. It may help people who encounter this problem in the future.