# MongoDB live server at http://127.0.0.1:27017/ says "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

Tags: mongodb, nginx, nginx-config

I have taken project from GitHub for my college project and I have no idea about this technology. The project is on creating online education platform. There where few errors like not having `.env` file in project to connect to server. I already fixed that. I downloaded MongoDB from official website and I started server on `127.0.0.1:27017` created new database named `virtual_class` and also created all the collection inside it (from his YouTube video | Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P7LzhL5i3w | GitHub link: https://github.com/MahbubulHasanSakib/virtual_classroom_deploy). I configured my `.env` file as `MONGOURI = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/virtual_class`. Now when I run the program  database is connected successfully but when I open the URL in browser `i.e., 127.0.0.1:27017` it says `It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.` I have searched many threads but all they provide is the solution for only Linux platform and not for Windows.

I tried to connect this project with nginx by configuring `nginx.conf` file as mentioned in [How to setup MongoDB behind Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853755/how-to-setup-mongodb-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy) Here is how I configured

```
events{
       ...
}
stream {
    server {
        listen  27017;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass    stream_mongo_backend;
    }

    upstream stream_mongo_backend {
      server 127.0.0.1:27017;
  }
}

http{
     ...
```

when i run localhost on port 80  it says

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

I have also tried [Cannot access mongodb through browser - It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446876/cannot-access-mongodb-through-browser-it-looks-like-you-are-trying-to-access-m) but it seems to be the solution for Linux platform

Hope my question is understood and sorry for bad English :)

Comment: Please remove mongoose-web-server tag from this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot connect to mongodb via HTTP. That means you cannot browse to it in your browser. The HTTP Interface and REST API was [removed](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#http-interface-and-rest-api) in version 3.6.

If you want to connect to your database you can use the [Node native driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-start/connect-to-mongodb/) or use the [mongosh](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/) shell.

There are a number of other Node packages that will allow you to connect such as [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) but that should be enough to get you started.

**Edit**:

I just checked the repo you are using and that app is listening on `process.env.PORT` so if you have already created your `.env` file and you have a `PORT` constant defined, for example, `PORT=3000`, then you can browse to your app on `http://localhost:3000/`. That repo is already using mongoose too so the app will be able to connect.